# Custom Object Returning Error: Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, types

I have a variable that will either be of a class `User` or `void`, the only problem is that when I run this code it gives me an error of : `Property 'forEach' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)`. I have tried to work around this a hundred different ways, but nothing works.

```
let friends: [User] | void = await this.getFriendsPosts(host);
friends.forEach(element => {

});
```

**Update:**

Here is my code for the function `this.getFriendsPosts(host)` and other subsequent functions:

```
async getFriendsPosts(host: User){
 let userFriendsID = host.friends
 let userFriends = []
 let retrievedPosts: [Post[]?] = []
 userFriendsID.map(async uid =>{
    let val = new User(await this.checkFriend(uid))
    userFriends.push(val)
    console.log(userFriends)
  })
 }


//*convert to users with promises
async checkFriend(uid){
  let metaData;
  let postInterface= [];
  let friendInterface : unknown;
  //*getting the post history
  let promise1 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    metaData = 
this.firestore.collection('Users').doc(uid.toString())
    let postData = metaData.collection('Posts')
    postData.valueChanges().subscribe(vals =>{
      vals.forEach(input => {
        postInterface.push({
          title: input.title,
          id: input.id,
          user: input.user,
          timebomb: input.timebomb,
          type: input.type,
          timestamp: input.timestamp
        } as complexPostInterface)      
      })
      res(vals)
    })
  })
  //*getting the user stats
  let promise2 = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    metaData.valueChanges().subscribe(vals =>{
      friendInterface = {
        name: vals.name,
        uid: vals.uid,
        nickname: vals.nickname,
        currentPosts: postInterface,
        status: new Post(postInterface[0] as any),
        timestamp: vals.timestamp,
      } as complexUserObj
      res(friendInterface as complexUserObj)
    })
  })
  await Promise.all([promise1,promise2])
  console.log(friendInterface)
  return (friendInterface)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your getFriendsPosts method should return undefined instead of void. Void should be used in functions whose return value will be ignored.

Property 'forEach' does not exist on undefined either, so you'll need to check first that friends exist:

```
let friends: [User] | undefined = await this.getFriendsPosts(host);
if (friends) {
  friends.forEach(element => {

  });
}
```

Or alternatively make the method return an empty array of Users and you don't need to check for it.

Comment: I am being returned the message: error TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type '[User]'.

Comment: It's hard to help without seeing the code, but it sounds to me like your function return type is still void.

Comment: The function uses a promise to return an array of users. So Promise<[User]> Also See Update on OP

Comment: It doesn't return anything.

Comment: You can see this by yourself, if you annotate the return type for the function:

`async getFriendsPosts(host: User): Promise<User[]>`